# android image translate not moving over action bar

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi I implemented an add to cart animation using this [How to implement Custom listview text animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002961/how-to-implement-custom-listview-text-animation). Here the TextView moves from list row to bottom corner into cart icon when clicking row item. Similarly, I implemented it for an image where when clicking a row item from the RecyclerView the image starts moving into cart.

But in my case **cart Icon is on the ActionBar** and my RecyclerView is in the ViewPager fragment. When clicking the row item in the Recycler the image translates till the ViewPager's tab layout (which is just below action bar) but it does not move over the action bar to touch the cart icon. Here is the animation code:

```
public void animateImage(String imageUrl, ImageView imageView) {
    if (null == anim) {
        anim = new ImageView(getActivity());

        int targetX = 800;
        int targetY = 0;

        int[] screenLocation = new int[2];
        imageView.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation);

        int x1 = screenLocation[0];
        int y1 = screenLocation[1];


        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = 300;
        layoutParams.height = 500;
        getActivity().addContentView(anim, layoutParams);
        Glide.with(getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(anim);

        anim.setTranslationX(x1);
        anim.setTranslationY(y1);


        anim.animate().scaleXBy(-0.5f).scaleYBy(-0.5f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (null != anim) {
                    anim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                anim = null;

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        }).setDuration(400)
                .translationX(targetX).translationY(targetY).start();


        }
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: I am surprise your code works as well as it seems to... So I am assuming you have list of items with images in a `RecyclerView` and when the user clicks on an item you want the image of the item to float over to the cart icon which is in your action bar?

Comment: @XaverKapeller yes exactly thats what i want..

Comment: @XaverKapeller any idea what could be the issue and any workarounds?? if i should post my fragment, activity n xml codes lemme know..